# Restful API with Laravel not working properly

Tags: laravel, rest

I've created a Restful API using Laravel 5.4. I am using postman to test this API. I am sending *postcode* and *building_number* in the body of the request. when I click on the Send button, I am getting Status code **200 OK** in the postman console but only getting postcode value in the response and not the building_number. Also, not getting the response message i.e.

```
  'msg' => 'found postcode',
```

Below is the screen shot from postman

[image: Postman response]

My route file is as

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){

    Route::post('paf', ['uses' => 'PafController@getAddress']);

});
```

and the controller is

**PafController**

```
public function getAddress(Request $request)
{
    $postcode = $request->input('postcode');
    $building_number = $request->input('building_number');

    $result = [
        'post_code' => $postcode,
        'building_number' => $building_number
    ];

    $response = [
        'msg' => 'found postcode',
        'address' => $result
    ];

    return response()->json($response, 200);
   }
```

please can someone advise why I am not getting back the full response?

Answer (score 1):

Define your route inside `routes/api.php` instead since it's an api you're building. This will automatically make `laravel-rest.dev/api/paf` available to you. All routes inside routes/api.php are prefixed with `/api`

`Route::post('paf', ['uses' => 'PafController@getAddress']);`

In postman select `form-data` option, right below body, instead of `raw`